# Starting NetworkManager before gdm.service with systemd

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, networkmanager, gdm3

In arch linux I would like to have `NetworkManager` service available at `gdm` login page.

I enabled the two services like this:

```
systemctl enable gdm.service
systemctl enable NetworkManager
```

The issue is that the wifi connects after I log in into gnome 3. As a result, any startup program / script (e.g. weather extension) relying to internet connection to do their stuff will fail as the connection is not yet available.

How can tell NetworkNamager to stat as soon as possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should write

```
[Unit]
Wants=NetworkManager.service
After=NetworkManager.service
```

to `/etc/systemd/system/gdm.service.d/after_networkmanager.conf`